# How can I use two html template in one angular project

Tags: angular

I am trying to develop an angular application, where there are two parts to the application. One part is the Admin part another part is the User part. In the Admin part, I want to use the Admin template which has its own CSS and js files. In the User part, I want to use the Landing page template which has also its own CSS and js files. I want to use these two templates in one angular project. Example: I have Admin LTE HTML template and Landing page HTML template. I have created an angular project called MyApp. Now I want to use Admin LTE and Landing page template both in MyApp. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

1. You have to generate two components with the angular cli(comand line interface). Open your favorite terminal at the path of your app.component.ts. Use the following command to generate a new component. `ng generate component <name of your component>`
2. Use the html template of your app.component and do for example:

```
<div *ngIf="isUserCondition"><app-your-landingpage-component></div>
<div *ngIf="isAdminCondition"><app-your-admin-component></div>
```

The `isUserCondition` and `isAdminCondition` are both booleans which you can set in the typescript file of your app.module. You have to fill the booleans in the way you decide a user is admin or not.

For further information I can recomend the angular page. For the component topic take a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components).

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am also facing a problem on initialization style link. In my Admin template I used bootstrap version 3.4.1 (oldest) and my Landing page template bootstrap version is 4.6. Now how can I initialize them?

Comment: You can use the styles url property. `styleUrls: ['./path/to/your/styles.css']`. this could you place in the @Component annotation in your ts file.

Answer (score 0):

At first there are two ways to do it, a simpler one if you only want to create a template for one type and another for another, and the more complex solution that would allow you to navigate, for example, different admin pages and on the other hand, navigation between the different pages. by user.
As I would do it?

**Simple solution**

As previously mentioned using an * ngIf in your HTML tags, this means that if the condition is met, it is displayed, and if it is not, it is not.
Ex:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isAdmin"><adminComponent></adminComponent></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isAdmin"><userComponent></userComponent></ng-container>
```

**Difficult but better solution**

The more complex solution requires you to know a bit of angular path management and use a guard.

In my case, this is how I created the route that would take you to backoffice (backoffice = part admin):

```
{
                path: paths.backoffice,
                loadChildren: './features/backoffice/backoffice.module#BackofficeModule',
                canActivate: [BackofficeGuard]
}
```

What does the guard contain? Very simple: I look for the user in a service of mine and check (in my case it has the admin attribute, which is a Boolean) if it is admin or not. If it is admin I return true so it will allow browsing and if it is false I do not return anything and send it to home.

```
export class BackofficeGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private stateService: StateService) {
    }

    isAdmin = false;

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ):
        | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
        | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
        | boolean
        | UrlTree {
        return this.stateService.getLoggedUser().pipe(
            map(user => {
                if (user.admin) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/home']);
                }
            })
        );
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }

}
```

That way you can enter your admin zone with a URL. And if you want to enter in a simpler way you can make a link that takes you to the URL admin, and it will only let you pass if you are admin.

Angular's guide to routing: https://angular.io/guide/router